backward_ros seems to be broken in recent rolling update
We're on Ubuntu Noble ros2 rolling distro.
We update to latest rolling syncs whenever it comes out each month. It seems starting a month or two ago, the backward_ros package, which emits a stack trace when a ros2 node crashes, doesn't do so anymore and rather emits a stack trace with just hex addresses. There haven't been any changes to our package definitions that could cause this. There aren't any changes to backward_ros repo so all I can think is that something in rolling changed to break backward_ros.
Are others experiencing this same problem? Any ideas what could be causing this?

Still not seeing any stack traces with latest rolling sync. I can't imagine that others are not seeing this problem.
